# nmcli dev disconnect iface wlan0 does not work anymore :(

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

if I do `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`, the network interface is turned off, and then turned on immediately (by network-manager, I guess), because it tries to re-connect, `nmcli con up down xxx` used to work in `12.04`, but now nothing happens and the only real way of turning networking on and off again is to untick\tick "Enable Wi-Fi" option in network manager (in "tray").

I used to stop networking via `nmcli dev disconnect iface wlan0`, but it does not seem to take any effect now, only unticking\ticking "Enable Wi-Fi" works :(

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that I have to disable auto-reconnection and use `nmcli nm wifi off && nmcli nm wifi on` to off\on it.